# cannot implicitly convert type int to bool

Tags: c#, c, int

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned int u, unsigned int v) {
// simple cases (termination)
if (u == v)
    return u;

if (u == 0)
    return v;

if (v == 0)
    return u;

// look for factors of 2
if (~u & 1) // u is even
    if (v & 1) // v is odd
        return gcd(u >> 1, v);
    else // both u and v are even
        return gcd(u >> 1, v >> 1) << 1;

if (~v & 1) // u is odd, v is even
    return gcd(u, v >> 1);

// reduce larger argument
if (u > v)
    return gcd((u - v) >> 1, v);

return gcd((v - u) >> 1, u);}
```

Собственно, скопировал код на C из википедии, пишу на C#. Ошибку выдаёт вот в таких моментах `if (~u & 1)` Не могу понять как исправить ситуацию, прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат выражения `~u & 1` - целое. `if` ожидает булевское значение.

```
if (~u & 1 != 0)
```

и так далее.